# How to make application stay active when its window is not selected?

Tags: windows

Is there a way to make app stay active without it needing to be on top? For example, I run some app, it starts to load, but loading is long, even 3 minutes, so I am not going to watch loading window for that long. But when I alt+tab from it, loading stops, and I need to alt+tab from application but also for it to keep loading.

Windows 10 64bit

Comment: This is entirely dependant on the application.  *Most* applications do not stop unless they are specifically programmed to do so.